# Custom Types' Names Even For Templates With Variadic Arguments

Tags: c++, templates

first of all we need a little introduction, so here we go. I'd like to write a functional struct that'll be able to retrieve name of a certain type, including templates. It'll return type's name from `type_info` or own defined custom name.

Here's a tiny logger which will need the name of a struct.

```cpp
#define LOG(x) FunctionLog(#x, x)

template<typename _Ty>
void FunctionLog(const char* name, const _Ty& value)
{
    // TypeName'll be introduced later.
    std::cout << name << ": " << static_cast<const char*>(TypeName<_Ty>::c_Name) << " = " << value << '\n';
}
```

```cpp
// Simple const char* wrapper, to easily concanate them with an operator|().
// I decided to use const char* instead of std::string due to memory.
struct CString
{
    const char* Content;

    explicit CString(const char* content)
        : Content(content) {}

    CString operator|(const CString& other)
    {
        return CString{ strcat(_strdup(Content), _strdup(other.Content)) };
    }

    operator const char*() const { return Content; }
};

template<typename _Ty>
struct TypeName
{
    static inline const CString c_Name = CString{ typeid(_Ty).name() };
}

// example of implementing that struct for std::vector<_Ty>
template<typename _Ty>
struct TypeName<std::vector<_Ty>>
{
    static inline const CString c_Name = CString{ "std::vector<" } | TypeName<_Ty>::c_Name | CString{ ">" };
};
```

And my problem is, how to make it work for `std::tuple`s as I don't know how to do that, because the tuple has a various number of template arguments. And I would like it to look like so: `std::tuple<int, int>` -> std::tuple<int, int>, `std::tuple<std::vector<int>, int>` -> std::tuple<std::vector< int>, int>. So every argument of that tuple template should call corresponding `TypeName<_Ty>`.

If something is unclear, please ask as I could miss something.

Comment: *"I decided to use `const char*` instead of `std::string` due to memory."* I would do the reverse according to the reason...

Comment: Your current `operator|` writes past allocated memory, and leaks memory.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Than I'll use `std::string`. I thought using `const char*` would make it better, but it turns out that not (maybe if I knew how to do that safely).

Comment: If you're interested, you may be able to do better than `typeid(T).name()`. You can write a "demangle" function that either uses `cxxabi.h` to `abi::__cxa_demangle`, for GNUC/Clang, or uses `typeid(T).raw_name()` for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want something like (C++17):

```
template<typename ... Ts>
struct TypeName<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    static inline const CString c_Name =
       (CString{ "std::tuple<" } | ... | TypeName<Ts>::c_Name) | CString{ ">" };
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know how to exactly use that triple dots.